# What happens when an aws autoscaling group member is destroyed and there are outstanding Spring async threads doing stuff?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, tomcat8, amazon-ec2

I have a Spring app that today uses `@Async` methods to take care of some non-essential, yet informative stuff.  It works great.

I want to move some new processing to this corner of the app, but I do not fully understand what would happen within the ec2 instance it is running on if it is shut down via AWS.

This app runs on Tomcat 8 in AWS as part of an Autoscaling group.  We deploy frequently, and scale up and down a lot, so machine termination is routine.  I understand that this may result in some threads to be halted mid-stream, and that is acceptable.

Existing use case:  "Report sales for the last hour to middle management via Slack."

I understand that a machine shutdown might cause that Slack message to be not posted, and that is OK.  It's only middle management.

New use case: "Report sales for the last day to senior management via email at 5:00am every day."

If this report takes a long time to run, it is much more likely that the thread running it will be halted if the power cable is yanked.

I know how to guard against this and make things "sort of atomic" via Redis etc, but that doesn't scale to continuous failure or when task duration eventually overtakes ec2 lifetime, and I would like a deeper understanding of how an ec2 instance "shutdown" command impacts an in-flight jvm thread that is currently running code via an `@Async` method invocation.

I do not want to run these things in Lambda or anything else out of band because our domain is in this codebase and updated frequently.

I have googled on this topic a bit, and almost all results yield topics of their app containers *not* shutting down in this scenario, which is the opposite of the info I am looking for.

Thanks!

-neil

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things to note here:

1. Directly answering your question:

   > What happens when an aws autoscaling group member is destroyed and
   >   there are outstanding Spring async threads doing stuff?

   Threads get InterruptedException.
2. The scenario your describing is not really suitable for Auto-scaling instances. Those were designed for handling traffic. You scenario is more about job processing. A dedicated (perhaps scheduled) instance (fleet) is more suitable for that. If you need to run many of these, you can schedule Spot instances to reduce costs. If you typically run the jobs on the traffic handling machines, it sounds like you are mixing concerns within the application, better split them.
3. Within the instance, I'd run the application which does some state management for jobs. You can write it yourself, using durable storage like DynamoDB (well Elasticache is alright but what if that fails?), or let some other tools do it for you (like Oozie, Chronos/Airflow, depending on what's your preferred language).

   If implementing yourself, there would be a record for each reporting interval (let's say a day). The state machine would be: `Not Running` (the same as absent), `Running`, `Failed`, `Done`. All but `Not Running` would have last update timestamp, which would be continuously updated on regular intervals for Running jobs. There would also be the instance/process/thread identifier of who owns the Running job. If the job is marked as Running but the update is missing for more than X intervals, you can declare the previous runner as failed, and the next instance that observes this, can take ownership of this job (update the owner).

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hacky-sounding answer, but assuming the critical `@Async` processing can happen to any box (or happens to all boxes), then can you just have the instance call the aws CLI when it starts critical processing and call it again when it is done? It should be able to enable *instance protection* that way.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html#instance-protection-instance

> Use the following update-auto-scaling-group command to enable instance protection for the specified Auto Scaling group:

```
aws autoscaling set-instance-protection --instance-ids i-5f2e8a0d --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --protected-from-scale-in
```

And elsewhere in the document:

> If all instances in an Auto Scaling group are protected from termination during scale in and a scale-in event occurs, Auto Scaling decrements the desired capacity. However, Auto Scaling can't terminate the required number of instances until their instance protection settings are disabled.
>
> Instance protection does not protect Auto Scaling instances from manual termination through the Amazon EC2 console, the terminate-instances command, or the TerminateInstances API. Instance protection does not protect an Auto Scaling instance from termination if it fails health checks and must be replaced. Also, instance protection does not protect Spot instances in an Auto Scaling group from interruption.

---

Alternatively, if only one box needs to run it, it should be possible to have a single dedicated instance protected as the *processing* box, and you just have to make sure that that instance is the one that does your critical async processing.

Comment: This doesn't protect the instance from termination if the entire cloudformation stack is "destroyed".  There is a policy for "retaining" an ec2 instance if the parent cloudformation stack is destroyed, but I can't find an api to flip that bit for a given instance.